# Signing a secret key with ECDSA

Tags: public-key, dsa

Assume Alice and Bob both separately come into possession of the same randomly generated 256 bit secret key.

Alice has Bob's public ECDSA key.

Alice wants to verify that Bob has possession of the 256 bit secret key.

Bob signs the 256 bit secret key and then stores this signature on a server.

Alice then verifies that Bob has possession of the secret key by verifying this signature.

Is it safe to store this signature on a server -- as in, does this signature reveal anything about the secret key to the server?

(Edited to better explain the goal)

Comment: It is better to use a hash and sign paradigm. In case of some mistake in the software implementation that [might leak the ECDSA key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Security). If you hashed then signed than the leak will only leak the hash not the 256 bits key. By the way what is your actual problem?

Comment: Good call! That works for my problem. Alice and Bob both come into possession of a secret key. The goal is for Alice to verify that Bob has possession of the key using Bob's public key and this signature.

Comment: Notice that verification of the signature requires knowledge of the data that was signed also. Plus if you're worried about integrity, notice you could rely on a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) instead of a signature scheme. (Depending on what's your use case for signing a secret key)

Comment: @Lery edited the question to explain the use case further. Both parties have knowledge of the data that was signed. My issue with a MAC is that both parties do not necessarily have access to an authentication key, but do have access to the others' public key.